Unable to get correct result using cv::calibrateHandEye
I have a camera mounted on a gimbal, and I need to find the rvec & tvec between the camera and the gimbal platform. So I did some research and this is my step:

Fixed the chessboard in one place, rotated the gimbal to different directions and take several pictures, note down the Pitch, Yaw and Roll axis rotation of the gimbal.
Use cv::calibrateCamera to get rvec and tvec for every chessboard in each picture. (re-projection error returned by the function was 0.130319)

auto criteria = cv::TermCriteria(cv::TermCriteria::EPS + cv::TermCriteria::COUNT, 40, 0.001);
cv::Size pattern_size(11, 8);

std::vector<cv::Point3f> objp;
for (int i{0}; i < pattern_size.height; i++)
{
    for (int j{0}; j < pattern_size.width; j++)
    {
        objp.emplace_back(j * 30, i * 30, 0);
    }
}

std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point3f>> object_points;
std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point2f>> image_points;
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
{
    cv::Mat gray = imread("20240727/" + std::to_string(i) + ".png", cv::IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
    if (std::vector<cv::Point2f> corners;
        findChessboardCorners(gray, pattern_size, corners))
    {
        cornerSubPix(gray, corners, cv::Size(8, 8), cv::Size(-1, -1), criteria);
        object_points.push_back(objp);
        image_points.push_back(corners);
    }
}

cv::Mat cameraMatrix, distCoeffs;
std::vector<cv::Mat> rvecs, tvecs;
const auto error = calibrateCamera(object_points, image_points, {1280, 1024}, cameraMatrix, distCoeffs, rvecs, tvecs);


Convert the Pitch, Yaw and Roll axis rotation to rotation matrix using this code:

const double z = gryo_data.at<double>(i, 1) * CV_PI / 180.0f,
             y = gryo_data.at<double>(i, 0) * CV_PI / 180.0f,
             x = gryo_data.at<double>(i, 2) * CV_PI / 180.0f;

cv::Mat r_z = (cv::Mat_<double>(3, 3, CV_64F) <<
    std::cos(z), -std::sin(z), 0,
    std::sin(z), std::cos(z), 0,
    0, 0, 1);

cv::Mat r_y = (cv::Mat_<double>(3, 3, CV_64F) <<
    std::cos(y), 0, std::sin(y),
    0, 1, 0,
    -std::sin(y), 0, std::cos(y));

cv::Mat r_x = (cv::Mat_<double>(3, 3, CV_64F) <<
    1, 0, 0,
    0, std::cos(x), -std::sin(x),
    0, std::sin(x), std::cos(x));

cv::Mat r = r_z * r_y * r_x;


call cv::calibrateHandEye using these parameters:

calibrateHandEye(r_gripper2base,  // rotation matrix get from step.3
                 t_gripper2base,  // I make this all zeros because my base is fixed on the ground
                 rvecs,           // std::vector<cv::Mat> rvecs return by cv::calibrateCamera
                 tvecs,           // std::vector<cv::Mat> tvecs return by cv::calibrateCamera
                 r_gripper2cam, t_gripper2cam,

I have multiple issues with these steps:

With different parameters pass into cv::cornerSubPix (and resulting different re-projection error in cv::calibrateCamera), I got cv::calibrateHandEye result with huge difference;
I got cv::calibrateHandEye result with huge difference by choosing different method (like CALIB_HAND_EYE_TSAI, CALIB_HAND_EYE_PARK...),
The final result is always far off the real measurement.

I first thought of there might be issues when converting pitch, yaw and roll rotation to rotation matrix, but I double checked the result by convert it back to pitch, yaw and roll rotation using the source of my robot, and the result is fine.
I also tried to transpose these matrix around (and I think I should't according to the doc), and the problem still persist.

Welcome to stackoverflow! Please ask only one question at a time! Provide a minimal reproducible example including working code and example images!
